# Trying to vectorize a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, vectorization

## UPDATE

Thanks to the help and suggestions of @CarlWitthoft my code was simplified to this:

```
model <- unlist(sapply(1:length(model.list),
         function(i) ifelse(length(model.list[[i]][model.lookup[[i]]] == "") == 0,
                            NA, model.list[[i]][model.lookup[[i]]])))
```

## ORIGINAL POST

Recently I read an article on how vectorizing operations in R instead of using for loops are a good practice, I have a piece of code where I used a big for loop and I'm trying to make it a vector operation but I cannot find the answer, could someone help me? Is it possible or do I need to change my approach? My code works fine with the for loop but I want to try the other way.

```
model <- c(0)
price <- c(0)
size <- c(0)
reviews <- c(0)
for(i in 1:length(model.list)) {
  if(length(model.list[[i]][model.lookup[[i]]] == "") == 0) {
    model[i] <- NA
  } else {
    model[i] <- model.list[[i]][model.lookup[[i]]]
  }
  if(length(model.list[[i]][price.lookup[[i]]] == "") == 0) {
    price[i] <- NA
  } else {
    price[i] <- model.list[[i]][price.lookup[[i]]]
  }
  if(length(model.list[[i]][reviews.lookup[[i]]] == "") == 0) {
    reviews[i] <- NA
  } else {
    reviews[i] <- model.list[[i]][reviews.lookup[[i]]]
  }
  size[i] <- product.link[[i]][size.lookup[[i]]]
}
```

Basically the `model.list` variable is a list from which I want to extract a particular vector, the location from that vector is given by the variables `model.lookup`, `price.lookup` and `reviews.lookup` which contain logical vectors with just one `TRUE` value which is used to return the desired vector from `model.list`. Then every cycle of the for loop the extracted vectors are stored on variables `model`, `price`, `size` and `reviews`.

Could this be changed to a vector operation?

Comment: Could this be changed to a vector operation? - Yes - the answer is almost always yes.  I suspect that you will have more luck with receiving an adequate answer if you make your question self-contained and reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, try to avoid `if` when not needed.   I think your desired output can be built as follows.

```
model <- unlist(sapply(1:length(model.list), function(i) model.list[[i]][model.lookup[[i]]]))
model[model=='']<-NA
```

And the same for your other variables. This assumes that all `model.lookup[[i]]` are of length one.  If they aren't, you won't be able to write the output to a single element of `model` in the first place.

I would also note that you are grossly overcoding, e.g. `x<-0` is better than `x<-c(0)`, and don't bother with `length` evaluation on a single item.

Comment: thanks for your response and recommendations. Your code works great but there's a little detail. How I replace this section of my code in your function?

if(length(model.list[[i]][model.lookup[[i]]] == "") == 0) {
    model[i] <- NA

What this part does, is that checks whether the value is zero and replace it by NA, your function just "skips" this situation and for example If I was expecting a 60 values vector I get a 59 values vector because this part was "skipped" by the sapply method. Hopefully I explained myself, sorry first time poster.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Your code has an "if / else" , so every element of `model[i]` is assigned either a value or NA.  My code first assigns values directly to all of `model[i]` and then replaces the `""` values with `NA` . If you are getting  a count error, it's not due to `sapply` .  Can you double-check the length of the sub-lists `model.list[[i]][model.lookup]` to make sure that they all have an i-th element? That is, that each `model.lookup` sublist is at least as long as the number of elements of `model.list` .

Comment: The ifelse function I added it later based on your code and now it's woriking just fine! My code ended like this:
`lookup <- function(i, arg1, arg2) {
  return(ifelse(length(arg1[[i]][arg2[[i]]]) == 0, NA, arg1[[i]][arg2[[i]]]))
}; 
model <- unlist(sapply(1:length(model.list),
                function(i) lookup(i, model.list, model.lookup)))` Sorry, I don't know how to edit response comments.